# Email Nativescript Chart

Tags: nativescript, email-attachments, radchart

I am working on a nativescript(using javascript)mobile application and using RadChart on one of the pages. 
I need to be able to open these chart on the default email client on the click of a button for user to be able to mail them. I did see that with the nativescript-email plugin we could send attachments, how do I attach the RadChart from the app to the email?
Or is there any way I could just open the RadChart page(from the mobile app) on to the mail client? Any other suggestions on how I could proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not open RadChart or any native UI component on email client. Email could be either plain text or Html only.

You could capture a screenshot of RadChart and email the image as an attachment in the email.

Use [nativescript-screenshot](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-screenshot) for taking screenshot of RadChart.
Use [nativescript-email](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-email) for sending email with attachment.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of how the screenshot image(from the nativescript-screenshot plugin) can be attached to the email? I am a nativescript newbie and not sure how to proceed with this,.

Comment: Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=2O9Fhx).

Comment: Perfect!! Just what I was looking for thank you so much for your help.